# Is $\operatorname{tr}(A^p)=\sum_{i_1}^n \sum_{i_2}^n \dots \sum_{i_p}^n a_{i_1 i_2} a_{i_2 i_3} \dots a_{i_p i_1}$? (Trace of matrix powers)

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't seem to find any information on the web to confirm this, but it works for up to t=3.

Comment: The trace of a matrix is equal to the trace of its transpose... And I don't even understand how you apply Einstein convention in your formula as all the indices are different.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net They are not all different, no.

Comment: The index $i_j$ appears in the $j$th, and $j-1$st element. But I suppose I need to fix that still.

Comment: You can prove by induction on $n$ that the $(i_1,i_{n+1})$-th element of $AB\dots L$ is $${a_{i_1i_2}b_{i_2i_3}\dots l_{i_ni_{n+1}}}$$ where there are $n$ matrices in the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll stick with your exponent $t$, even though that's easily mistaken for a transpose symbol. You missed one factor: you should have $\operatorname{tr}A^t=(A^t)_{i_1i_1}=A_{i_1i_2}\cdots A_{i_ti_1}$. In particular, we can prove by induction on $t$ that $(A^t)_{i_1i_0}=A_{i_1i_2}\cdots A_{i_ti_0}$; then we just take the trace. (In the inductive step, note that $A_{i_1i_2}\cdots A_{i_tj}A_{ji_0}=A_{i_1i_2}\cdots A_{i_ti_{t+1}}A_{i_{t+1}i_0}$.)

In the case $t=3$ you mentioned, the labelling $i=i_1$ etc. lets us write $\operatorname{tr}A^3=A_{ij}A_{jk}A_{ki}$. This looks very satisfying if you know anything about either quaternions or the cross product in $3$ dimensions, even though it has nothing to do with either of them.

Comment: Thank you! But where did this come from, do you know the proof?

Comment: @BrendonEspinoza See edit.